# How do I keep a log of all commands and how long it took

Tags: linux, logs, command, command-history, time

I know I can currently run time ls and get the time it took to run that command. I can also output that to a file easily. How do I automatically do this for every command?

Comment: Which shell? What OS? Same file, or individual -- per instance? For each?

Comment: Too vague. In addition to Jeff's on-point questions, I'd also like to know how secure you need this to be (i.e., is it OK if someone runs `/bin/bash` and defeats your time logger?), and, as always, what you've already tried, and how well it worked/didn't work. Your question history indicates this may be becoming a pattern. After all, we're here to *help,* not be your developer slaves. ;-)

Comment: Try `accton(8)` and friends.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I'm using ubuntu and just for my own account thats logged in. same file.  Dont care about security.

Comment: Have you looked at `history` or do you want something more encompassing.